# How does `this` work in higher order components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, components, higher-order-functions

I'm learning about higher order components from this [site](http://reactpatterns.com/#Higher-order%20component), but don't get how `this` works inside one. Looking at the below, is the `this` in the constructor referring to what's being returned, as in the final resulting component? And the `this` that is in `{...this.props}` is the `Connect` component? How can `this` refer to 2 different things here?

Stateless Component

```
const Greeting = ({ name }) => {
  if (!name) { return <div>Connecting...</div> }

  return <div>Hi {name}!</div>
}
```

Higher Order Component

```
const Connect = ComposedComponent =>
  class extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
      super()
      this.state = { name: "" }
    }

componentDidMount() {
  // this would fetch or connect to a store
  this.setState({ name: "Michael" })
}

render() {
  return (
    <ComposedComponent
      {...this.props}
      name={this.state.name}
    />
  )
}
```

}

Comment: It works exactly the same as in any other component. *" Looking at the below, is the this in the constructor referring to what's being returned, as in the final resulting component?"* It refers to an instance of the `class`. *"How can this refer to 2 different things here?"* It doesn't. It refers to the same instance.

Answer (score 1):

> is the this in the constructor referring to what's being returned, as in the final resulting component? And the this that is in {...this.props} is the Connect component?

`Connect` is a function, not a component.
Connect is a function the recieves `ComposedComponent` and returns a new Component. The `this` referrals are for the returned (parent) component. In the constructors it initializes that component's state, and in `render` it passes its' props to `ComposedComponent`.

Comment: how is it getting its props?

Comment: Same way he's accessing its' state in `constructor`. Both `counstructor` and `render` are functions of this component, and by that, `this` refers to that component, which has state and props as properties.

Comment: I don't think this explanation could get much better. It's really good. "This" refers to the object, but props and state are keys/properties of your scoped object. The "this" you see anywhere within class extends React.Component {...} are one and the same.